# Why does my mousefollow method not work on different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Here is a link to the code pen
https://codepen.io/shahman28/pen/mdXraRE

This is a part of a larger project that I am working on. I am attempting to place circles when the mouse is clicked. As you can see in the codepen above the mouse follows well and places the circles at the correct locations, but when I try to do it in browser the cursor has an offset from the mouse and the circles are placed incorrectly. In firefox it is completely arbitrary, but in chrome it places them in the location of the cursor(which is in the incorrect location). I am recycling some code from previous projects so that is why there is the border in the html and css.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

points = [];
class Mouse {
  constructor(c) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.easing = 0.05;

    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    canvas.onmousemove = e => {
      this.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
      this.y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    }
  }

}

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function random_hex_color_code() {
  let n = (Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16);
  return '#' + n.slice(0, 6);
};

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.clientX - rect.left
  y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  point = new Point(x, y, '#FF0000');
  points.push(point);
})
w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
  h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
  mousePosition = new Mouse(canvas);


function animate() {

  ctx.fillStyle = '#4A7DB9';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function handlePoints() {
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i].draw();
  }
}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  handlePoints();
  animate();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

#canvas1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device.width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tower Defense</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="start()">Start Combat</button>
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know how to make it so that the the cursor and placed arcs are consistent?

Comment: I believe you should be using `canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ...);` Though @zergski's answer would explain why it just straight up appears not to work.

Comment: `when I try to do it in browser` - the codepen IS in browser ... so

Comment: console.log() and figure out what is different.

Comment: it also works exactly the same in firefox and chrum - so you're probably doing it wrong

Comment: "_in the location of the cursor (which is in the incorrect location)._" That's where the code explicitly places the spot (in CodePen example and in both mentioned browsers). Where do you want to place the spot instead?  Can you also elaborate "_in browser_", do you mean on your own page where you're running this?

Comment: Your problem relates to the sizing of the canvas. At one point you fix its dimensions in the stylesheet and then in the code you set the width and height attributes to the viewport. When I remove the stylesheet setting it works fine (on Edge/Chrome and FF). So, which do you want, is it to fill the whole viewport or be of a fixed px setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that at one point the canvas is set to have fixed px dimensions and at another point it is set to have the dimensions of the viewport.

This snippet removes the settings in the stylesheet and just uses viewport dimensions. It seems to work fine (tested on Windows10 Edge/Chrome and Firefox).

You need to decide which setting you want and to stick with that rather than try to use both which leads to the inconsistency.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

points = [];
class Mouse {
  constructor(c) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.easing = 0.05;

    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    canvas.onmousemove = e => {
      this.x = e.clientX - rect.left;
      this.y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    }
  }

}

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function random_hex_color_code() {
  let n = (Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16);
  return '#' + n.slice(0, 6);
};

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.clientX - rect.left
  y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  point = new Point(x, y, '#FF0000');
  points.push(point);
})
w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
  h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
  mousePosition = new Mouse(canvas);


function animate() {

  ctx.fillStyle = '#4A7DB9';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function handlePoints() {
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i].draw();
  }
}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  handlePoints();
  animate();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

#canvas1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left 0;
  top: 0;
  /* removed 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  */
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device.width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--<button onClick = "start()">Start Combat</button>-->
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works thank you. I made the canvas resizable by wrapping the canvas in a div, and setting the width of the canvas equal to the div in javascript.